# SQL Server Query Taking Too Long Handling?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, raiserror

I have a complex query inside a stored proc. Within the proc itself, I would like to judge how long things are taking and do a RAISERROR if I think a 30-second threshhold has been passed (which will force people to do some optimizations).

Can anyone say a decent way to make that happen, all within TSQL code?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you enforce a command timeout in the application? If not I think you'd need service broker.

Comment: timeouts are better handled by the calling code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could issue a [`set query_governor_cost_limit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176100.aspx) before commencing on the potentially costly query. However, I believe that this cancels the query before it starts (if it's estimated to take too long), rather than cancelling it when the limit is actually reached.